# Recovering ZFS pool with errors on import

Tags: linux, zfs

I have a machine that had some trouble with some bad RAM. After I diagnosed it and removed the offending stick of RAM, The ZFS pool in the machine was trying to access drives by using incorrect device names. I simply exported the pool and re-imported it to correct this. However I am now getting this error.

The pool Storage no longer automatically mounts

```
sqeaky@sqeaky-media-server:/$ sudo zpool status
no pools available
```

A regular import says its corrupt

```
sqeaky@sqeaky-media-server:/$ sudo zpool import
  pool: Storage
    id: 13247750448079582452
 state: UNAVAIL
status: The pool is formatted using an older on-disk version.
action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
config:

    Storage                 UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      raidz1                UNAVAIL  corrupted data
        805066522130738790  ONLINE
        sdd3                ONLINE
        sda3                ONLINE
        sdc                 ONLINE
```

A specific import says the vdev configuration is invalid

```
sqeaky@sqeaky-media-server:/$ sudo zpool import Storage
cannot import 'Storage': invalid vdev configuration
```

Cannot offline or detach the drive because the pool cannot be started/imported

```
sqeaky@sqeaky-media-server:/$ sudo zpool offline Storage 805066522130738790
cannot open 'Storage': no such pool
sqeaky@sqeaky-media-server:/$ sudo zpool detach Storage 805066522130738790
cannot open 'Storage': no such pool
```

Cannot force the import

```
sqeaky@sqeaky-media-server:/$ sudo zpool import -f Storage 
cannot import 'Storage': invalid vdev configuration
```

I should have 4 devices in my ZFS pool:

> /dev/sda3
>   /dev/sdd3
>   /dev/sdc
>   /dev/sdb

I have no clue what 805066522130738790 is but I plan on investigating further. I am also trying to figure out how to use zdb to get more information about what the pool thinks is going on.

For reference This was setup this way, because at the time this machine/pool was setup it needed certain Linux features and booting from ZFS wasn't yet supported in Linux. The partitions sda1 and sdd1 are in a raid 1 for the operating system and sdd2 and sda2 are in a raid1 for the swap.

Any clue on how to recover this ZFS pool?

Edit - Status update
I figured out what 805066522130738790 is. It is some guid that ZFS was failing to use to identify /dev/sdb. When physically I remove /dev/sdb the pool mounts and comes online. But I still cannot swap out the disks. I guess I will back up the files to external media, then blow away the whole pool because it is too corrupt to continue functioning. I should have just had good backups from the start...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using ZFS on FUSE?  I wouldn't expect that to be anywhere near stable anyway.

I'd offline the weird drive, then re-add it and see if that helps.  You might also try forcing the re-import of the pool.
http://docs.huihoo.com/opensolaris/solaris-zfs-administration-guide/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: Nice Ideas, I tried them, but to no avail. I added the results to my question.

Why would you expect ZFS fuse to be unstable? I have not heard many reports of instability.

Comment: Did you upgrade ZFS on FUSE?  Taken from `status: The pool is formatted using an older on-disk version.`.  Maybe try zpool upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the zfs-discuss list if you want real debugging help:

http://mail.opensolaris.org/mailman/listinfo/zfs-discuss
http://opensolaris.org/jive/forum.jspa?forumID=80

(Same list, just different interfaces.)

Comment: I will take a look at this.